# How to foreach all inputs that starts with specific class prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple inputs:

```
<input class="pdf-in pdf-bg custom-inbox pdf-bg-3 rate_1 cant_be_empty" type="text" onchange="doMultiplication(1)" onkeyup="doMultiplication(1)">
<input class="pdf-in pdf-bg custom-inbox pdf-bg-3 rate_2 cant_be_empty" type="text" onchange="doMultiplication(2)" onkeyup="doMultiplication(2)">
```

I want to loop through them and get the values. This is my code:

```
$("input[class^='rate_']").each(function() {
    alert('hi');
    totalTime = timeSum(totalTime, $(this).val());
});
```

It's not working. Any ideas?

Note that these fields are being generated by an AJAX call.

Comment: `"input[class^='rate_']"` means all elements which `class` attribute starts with `rate_` in your case this doesn't a case.

Comment: It's not working as the `class` attribute starts with `pdf-in`. To do what you need, use one of the explicit classes already on the elements and loop over that

Comment: my inputs have a class that starts with "rate_"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since they are generated by AJAX call, it is better to send execute them on the `success` callback. If that's not possible, you can use [`$.ajaxComplete()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/).

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $("input[class^='rate_']").each(function() {
    alert('hi');
    totalTime = timeSum(totalTime, $(this).val());
  });
});
```

Also the problem here is that, the classes may **not always** start with the name. So you need to use:

```
$("input[class^='rate_'], input[class*=' rate_']")
```

Your final code would be:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $("input[class^='rate_'], input[class*=' rate_']").each(function() {
    alert('hi');
    totalTime = timeSum(totalTime, $(this).val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use name attribute instead of class to the inputs, like this:

```js
$("input[name^='rate_']").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val())
    //totalTime = timeSum(totalTime,$(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="pdf-in pdf-bg custom-inbox pdf-bg-3 rate_1 cant_be_empty" type="text" onchange="doMultiplication(1)" onkeyup="doMultiplication(1)" value="Value 1" name="rate_1">
<input class="pdf-in pdf-bg custom-inbox pdf-bg-3 rate_2 cant_be_empty" type="text" onchange="doMultiplication(2)" onkeyup="doMultiplication(2)" value="Value 2" name="rate_2">
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working cause you have several classes in your `input`.

```js
$("input").each(function() {

   console.log($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="pdf-in pdf-bg custom-inbox pdf-bg-3 rate_1 cant_be_empty" type="text" onchange="doMultiplication(1)" onkeyup="doMultiplication(1)">
<input class="pdf-in pdf-bg custom-inbox pdf-bg-3 rate_2 cant_be_empty" type="text" onchange="doMultiplication(2)" onkeyup="doMultiplication(2)">
```

Two options are offered to you:

1. Check simply the inputs like this `$("input").each`; retrieve the `class` attribute; split it; and check if it's containing the class `rate_`:

```js
$("input").each(function() {
var exist=false;
var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
    $.each(classes,function(index,value){
     if(value.indexOf("rate_") !== -1){
     exist=true;
     }
   });
   console.log(exist);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="pdf-in pdf-bg custom-inbox pdf-bg-3 rate_1 cant_be_empty" type="text" onchange="doMultiplication(1)" onkeyup="doMultiplication(1)">
<input class="pdf-in pdf-bg custom-inbox pdf-bg-3 rate_2 cant_be_empty" type="text" onchange="doMultiplication(2)" onkeyup="doMultiplication(2)">
<input class="pdf-in pdf-bg custom-inbox pdf-bg-3  cant_be_empty" type="text" onchange="doMultiplication(2)" onkeyup="doMultiplication(2)">
```

2. Select the `input` if the `"rate_"` substring exists in its `class` attribute:

```js
$("input[class*='rate_']").each(function() {
    alert('exist');
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="pdf-in pdf-bg custom-inbox pdf-bg-3 rate_1 cant_be_empty" type="text" onchange="doMultiplication(1)" onkeyup="doMultiplication(1)">
<input class="pdf-in pdf-bg custom-inbox pdf-bg-3 rate_2 cant_be_empty" type="text" onchange="doMultiplication(2)" onkeyup="doMultiplication(2)">
```